# How to find root of $ x^n+ax+b=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I remember that there should be a formula for computing the root of $x^n+ax+b=0$. But I can't find it online. Could anybody point me the solutions? Thanks.

Comment: Seems likely that there would be $n$ roots?

Comment: By the way if you just put your math between dollars signs it usually looks much better. x^n+ax+b=0 becomes  $x^n+ax+b=0$ just by putting it in between two dollar signs

Comment: To add to Ovi's comment: For some basic information about writing maths at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: You can have a look to Glasser's derivation  in the link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical

Answer (score 2):

If by a "formula" you mean an expression in radicals, then you remember incorrectly.  The polynomial $x^5-x+1$ has no solutions in radicals. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring%E2%80%93Jerrard_normal_form#Bring.E2.80.93Jerrard_normal_form

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2507093/why-is-there-no-solution-with-radicals-for-the-quintic-equation-x5-x1-0 exchange post that explains why x^5 - x + 1 is not solveable by radicals using galois theory