# Why is there no solution with radicals for the quintic equation $x^5-x+1=0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, quintics

I'm looking for solution for this equation
$$
x^5-x+1=0.
$$ 
I know that there is no solution with radicals. But, I can not find possible solutions (in MSE  or  internet resource).

I know [Abel-Ruffini theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem). But, this is so hard for general form.

> **Question**: Can you please show me in this particular case why there is not solution with radicals?

Comment: [Even wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E5-x%2B1%3D0) doesn't know the exact forms for the solutions, only approximations.

Comment: I know wolfram alpha..

Comment: To see why there are no solutions with radicals, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/837948/proving-that-a-polynomial-is-not-solvable-by-radicals) (for a slightly different polynomial).

Comment: In general, if the polynomial has rational roots we can apply https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem. But other than that, you would need numerical methods to find them.

Comment: That is strange: [Bring radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical) has not been mentioned yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are familiar with the use of Galois theory, then this particular polynomial can be handled as follows. Let $G$ be the Galois group of this polynomial.

1. It is irreducible over $\Bbb{Z}$ (hence over $\Bbb{Q}$) because it is irreducible over $\Bbb{Z}_5$. See [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81583/11619) for many ways of seeing that. Consequently we can view $G$ as a transitive subgroup of $S_5$. In particular $G$ contains an element $\tau$ of order five which obviously must be a $5$-cycle.
2. Modulo two it factors as $$x^5-x+1\equiv(x^2+x+1)(x^3+x^2+1)$$ a product of an irreducible quadratic and an irreducible cubic. By [Dedekind's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/160855/11619) the group $G$ thus contains an element $\sigma$ with cycle type $(2,3)$.
3. The permutation $\sigma$ is odd, and it has order six. Therefore $|G|$ is divisible by $30$, and $G$ is not subgroup of $A_5$. It follows (from a census of subgroups of $S_5$) that $G$ must be all of $S_5$.
4. The group $G$ is not solvable, so by one of the main results of Galois theory the zeros of your polynomial cannot come from a field gotten as [a root tower extension of $\Bbb{Q}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_extension).

Comment: Dedekind's theorem with modulo 5 seems to prove that there is a $5$-cycle in $G$. However, I don't see how it follows from $G$ being transitive. Is it a general fact that all transitive subgroups of $S_n$ contains an $n$-cycle, or is there something else at work here?

Comment: @Arthur. No, not all transitive subgroups of $S_n$ contain an $n$-cycle. The smallest example is that copy of (a transitive) Klein four as a  subgroup of $A_4$. But, when $n$ is a prime, $n=p$, then a transitive subgroup $G$ of $S_p$ does contain a $p$-cycle. This is because by orbit-stabilizer we have $p\mid |G|$, so by Cauchy there is an element of order $p$ in $G$. But such an element is necessarily a $p$-cycle. Sorry about leaving the answer a bit too sketchy at that point :-/

Comment: Wow... Thank you for amazing answer.

Answer (score 4):

There are solutions in terms of hypergeometric functions: for example,

$${\mbox{$_4$F$_3$}(1/5,2/5,3/5,4/5;\,1/2,3/4,5/4;\,{3125}/{256})}$$

See e.g. [this article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042700002879).

Comment: maybe, after 1000 years, can radical solutions be found?

Comment: No: theorems never get repealed.

Comment: Teacher,Can you explain me, is this function express all $5$ roots? Or 1$ root?

Comment: This is one root.  There are ways to express the others.